# Haskell: 'makeNtuple' function?

Tags: haskell, tuples

Is there a function or functions in Haskell that takes n arguments, and returns an n-tuple? For example:

```
make3tuple:: a -> a -> a -> (a,a,a)
make3tuple a b c = (a,b,c)
```

ie: like comma, but for more than two arguments.  Obviously make3tuple does the job, but I feel like there must be a built-in way to do this, and I've not found it, or missed some way to use some other ubiquitous function.

FWIW, this arises when using liftM3 (or higher). For example:

```
type RandomState a = State StdGen a
[...]
getTwoRandoms = liftM2 (,) getRandom getRandom
get3Randoms = liftM3 make3tuple getRandom getRandom getRandom
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

```
(,,) :: a -> b -> c -> (a, b, c)
(,,,) :: a -> b -> c -> d -> (a, b, c, d)
```

etc.

So you could write `liftM3 (,,) getRandom getRandom getRandom`

Haskell compilers provide functions like this up to a certain size (I think the guarantee is 15-tuples)

Comment: With an extension called `TupleSections`, you can even partially apply this. So `(,1,,2)` is equal to `\ x y -> (x,1,y,2)`.

Comment: @amindfv Hahahahaha... it obviously hadn't occurred to me that comma could be used like that.  Thanks!

Comment: @gwideman: Note that these are their own operators: `(,,)` is totally different than `(,) (,)`. If you were to try and compose them, you'd get something like: `(,) ((,) 3 4) 5`, which is `((3,4),5)`

Comment: @amindfv: Interesting, that got me looking at Tuple.hs where these are defined.  You correctly guessed that I'd assumed it was some mystical way of composing comma, when actually these are individual functions defined in a pedestrian way. Thanks

Comment: @gwideman: I guessed that because I made the same assumption once :)

Answer (score 1):

Not as a function like `makeNtuple :: Int -> a -> a -> ... -> (a,a,...)` and note it seems to even be non-expressible in the type language. If you're okay with the tuple having a homogenous type then you can use ["dependently-typed" `Vector`s](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism-and-promotion.html)

```
data Nat = Ze | Su Nat

data Vec :: * -> Nat -> * where
  Nil  :: Vec a Ze
  Cons :: a -> Vec a n -> Vec a (Su n)
```

Comment: Fair enough... indeed I wasn't expecting a general makeNtuple with variable-length arg list.  That can sort of be done with lists and zip.

Comment: BTW there is a well-developed library on hackage for it: [fixed-vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-vector)